# Как регулировать громкость аудиофайла на джава?

Tags: java, аудио

Мне надо добавить звуки (музыку и эффекты) в игру, поискал в интернете, нашёл 2 способа реализации, 1 через базовые библиотеки джава (Clip, AudioInputStream и AudioSystem), и 2 с помощи библиотеки JLayer (JavaZoom), но оба они мне не очень подходят, так как ни 1 ни 2 способ не дают возможности регулировать громкость воспроизводимого звука, через FloatControl можно поменять громкость всех звуков разом, а мне надо что-бы каждый звук (объект звука) имел возможность менять громкость отдельно. Каким образом мне это сделать? Какая библиотека может мне в этом помочь? Возможно есть какие-то способы реализации используя 1 или 2 способ воспроизведения звука выше? (JavaFX не вариант)